# dnsmasq listen on 0.0.0.0 when started by NetworkManager

Tags: dnsmasq, networkmanager

Is it possible to configure NetworkManager or dnsmasq to listen on 0.0.0.0 when dnsmasq is started by NetworkManager process ?

I have noticed whatever I put in */etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/00-example.conf* file, like:

```
listen-address=0.0.0.0
```

dnsmasq is started with following arguments by NetworkManager:

```
/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

Any idea how to change *--listen-address* option ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on Ubuntu, what happens here is that **dnsmasq** is used by Network Manager as **plugin** to cache your local dns queries, reason why it's predefined on the command line :

```
--listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

So in order to make a configuration for your **local** network, you will need to disable the default dnsmasq, by commenting out the line under the above file **/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf** :

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

Once done, restart NM :

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Then you will need to install a **standard** version of dnsmasq and use it for your own purpose.

**COMPLEMENTARY** : 
Once the standard version installed on one of your servers, this will be your DNS server, it should have a **fixed** ip since you are using dhcp server for your network, finally to make your dns server listening on all its **ips** not only on the **loopback (127.0.0.1) ** you should put under the config file **/etc/dnsmasq.conf** :

```
listen-address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: but then I need to know in advance IP address(es) of DNS server(s). If I switch on another network, _NetworkManager_ will get new IP address from dhcp server, and update _dnsmasq_ with new IPs of DNS servers. If I use standalone _dnsmasq_, I need to configure DNS servers in advance. Right ? Or there is a way to configure _NetworkManager_ to update _/etc/resolve.conf_ file with new DNS servers everytime I join new network.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this too.  I think Reda Salih probably has the correct answer.  But I had already invested a lot of time in trying to bend NetworkManager to my will, and I finally got it working.  Just wanted to add my answer:

1. Make sure your host has a Static IP.  If you use DHCP (even with static allocation) DnsMasq will pick up undesirable settings such as using a different DNS server for local addresses.
2. Don't put local IPs in `/etc/hosts`, as that won't be read.  Use `addn-hosts` option with a different file.
3. Set `dhcp-option=3` to your gateway if it is different than this Dnsmasq host (mine is).
4. Do NOT set `dhcp-option=6` (unless you know what you're doing)
5. To override the `listen-addr` setting forced by NetworkManager, you can use the `interface` setting in the conf file.  I have mine set to `interface=eth0,lo` which for me is equiv to `listen-addr=0.0.0.0`.
   Other settings (such as dhcp-host) are normal and don't need additional mention.